# Integration test with thymeleaf and webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

I am not sure how to test thymeleaf controller views in a spring boot webflux application.
The following gives 404 BAD REQUEST:

```
        webTestClient.get()
                .uri("/customer-view")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)a
                .exchange().isOk
```

I believe that webTestClient doesn't give any server-side views testing support, only mockMvc. But I have only the webflux dependency "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux", and mockMvc is not present in webflux as it's a blocking client of course.

I am wondering if there is a way to test a thymeleaf view in webflux. For example a method like the following:

```
  @Controller
  class CustomerController {

@GetMapping("/customer-view")
suspend fun getCustomerView(model: Model
): String {
    val customer = customerService.getCustomer()
    model["customer"] = customer
    return "customer-view"
}
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: I find mockMvc (or webTestClient) not so useful for testing your Thymeleaf UI. I rather use Cypress (or Playwright, but have not used that yet). You can integrate Cypress into your Maven/Gradle build via https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/testcontainers-cypress (note: I am the author).

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is thymeleaf requires resources to be present, so while you are testing you need to load resources as well.

```
@Controller
class CustomerController {
    @GetMapping("/customer-view")
    suspend fun getCustomerView(model:Model):String{
        model["something"] = "this is an example"
        return "customer-view"
    }
}

// make sure that your html template here -> /resource/templates/cusotmer-view.html . Remember to add xmlns attribute to your template, too.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymelaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:text="${something}"/>
</body>
</html>

// Now you can test this

import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxTest
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient
// Again you need resources so add this annotation @WebFluxTest to load them
@WebFluxTest
class CustomerControllerTest{
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var webTestClient: WebTestClient

    @Test
    fun testReturns200Ok() {
        runBlocking {
            webTestClient
                .get()
                .uri("/customer-view")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk
        }
    }
}

// I hope this helps
```

Answer (score -1):

Modifying umit's answer - removing blocking

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@WebFluxTest(CustomerController::class)
class CustomerControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var webTestClient: WebTestClient


  @Test
  fun `should return customer view`() {
    val customer = Customer("John", "Doe")
    `when`(customerService.getCustomer()).thenReturn(customer)

    webTestClient.get().uri("/customer-view")
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk
        .expectBody<String>()
        .consumeWith {
            //assertions
        }
  }
}
```